# How do I split a div into multiple clickable section?

Tags: css, html

I am just getting back into HTML for the first time in years, and I appreciate the help that I have received from other Q&A's, but I cannot seem to find a solution for my most recent challenge.

I am using DIVs to run JS using the onclick() functionality. In my most recent improvement I am looking to section off a DIV into multiple horizontal sections (which I know is possible), but I would like the text to continue to flow through out the sections. I will try to show an example of what I am trying to do:

---

l  TITLE FOR ENTIRE DIV
l
l Selection 1     l Section 2     l Section 3

I would like each section's clickable range to continue vertically up into the title text. How would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: can you juse use multiple divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You layer it. Put the title div on top or below (and make the section divs transparent).
With z-index you can put divs up or down in layers. You just need to position them with absolute, because in-line (default) they will not overlap). You can also position them relative.

```
div.title {height: 2em;}
div.section {
position: relative;
top : -2em;
padding-top : 2em; (so the section text starts lower)
z-index: 999;
}
```

There are various other ways to accomplish this. The best depends on how the rest of your site looks like and how it messes the least with everything else.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know layers were possible, I will research layers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

```css
#title{background-color:red;}
#menu ul{position:absolute;top:0px;left:40px;}
#menu ul li{display:inline-block;list-style-type:none;height:32px;width:132px;border-right:1px solid green;text-align:center;background-color:rgba(155,155,155,0.4);}
```

```html
<div id="title">Rampant Reds Fan</div>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <a href=""><li>Rampant</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>Reds</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>Fan</li></a>
   </ul>
  </div>
```